# How to use asyncio with a very long list of tasks (generator)

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio

I have a small program that loads a pretty heavy CSV (over 800MB, in chunks, using `pandas.read_csv` to limit memory usage) and performs a few API calls to servers "out in the wild", and finally builds a result object which is then stored in a database.

I have added caching for the network requests where possible, but even then, the code takes over 10 hours to complete. When I profile the code with PySpy, most of it is waiting for network requests.

I tried converting it to use asyncio to speed things up, and have managed to get the code to work on a small subset of the input file. However with the full file, the memory use become prohibitive.

Here is what I have tried:

```py
import pandas as pd
import httpx

async def process_item(item, client):
    # send a few requests with httpx session
    # process results
    await save_results_to_db(res)

async def get_items_from_csv():
    # loads the heavy CSV file
    for chunk in pd.read_csv(filename, ...):
        for row in chunk.itertuples():
            item = item_from_row(row)
            yield item

async def main():
    async with httpx.AsyncClient() as client:
        tasks = []
        for item in get_items_from_csv():
            tasks.append(process_item(item, client))
        await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

asyncio.run(main())
```

Is there a way to avoid creating the `tasks` list, which becomes a very heavy object with over 1.5M items in it? The other downside of this is that no task seems to be processed until the entire file has been read, which is not ideal.
I'm using python 3.7 but can easily upgrade to 3.8 if needed.

Comment: Not sure, but does it reall make sense to execute all the tasks in 'parallel'?

Why don't you create only for example 100 tasks in one go, await / gather  and launch then the next bunch of tasks

Comment: I am not sure either. Intuitively, the process gets a mix of data from disk, database and network and then writes back to the database. If I run in batches, I think it would mean waiting for one batch to complete before the next one starts. I suspect at the start and end of batches, only one of the "slow" resources would be used, meaning the overall process would not be as fast as it can. But again, this is just a guess, I would need to figure out how to profile the code to confirm that hunch.

Comment: Executing in batches as I suggest would not be as fast as possible, but I would give it a shot.
I'd expect it go give you a considerable speed up. 
you might play with the amount of tasks.

If this strategy works, then you could try to change it  such, that as soon as at least one task is finished a new one is added. but running all tasks in parallel is as you noticed, probably not what you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for here is not running in batches but running `N` workers which concurrently pull tasks off a queue.

```py
N = 10  # scale based on the processing power and memory you have

async def main():
    async with httpx.AsyncClient() as client:
        tasks = asyncio.Queue()
        for item in get_items_from_csv():
            tasks.put_nowait(process_item(item, client))

        async def worker():
            while not tasks.empty():
                await tasks.get_nowait()
            # for a server
            # while task := await tasks.get():
            #     await task

        await asyncio.gather(*[worker() for _ in range(N)])
```

I used an `asyncio.Queue` but you can also just use a `collections.deque` since all tasks get added to the queue prior to starting a worker. The former is especially useful when running workers that run in a long running process (e.g. a server) where items may be asynchronously queued.

Comment: What's the point of running multiple "worker" coroutines, since they will all be run by the same event loop? Shouldn't we submit work to a `ThreadPoolExecutor` to process tasks concurrently?

Comment: @acl the point of the worker coroutines is to set the "magnitude" of asynchrony of the task processing; in the context of async, your functions should be implemented such that they don't block the event loop for "too long" (which depends on what you are doing), if you need to run blocking functions, use [`asyncio.to_thread`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.to_thread) but this won't give you the advantages of parallelism due to the GIL, which you can sidestep with [`ProcessPoolExecutor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#processpoolexecutor)